# Js animation does not work

Tags: javascript, jquery, animation, letters

Js animation letters does not work.

> Console :index.php:29 Uncaught ReferenceError: $ is not defined    at
>   index.php:29. Black letters without animation.

```
$('.ml11 .letters').each(function(){
    $(this).html($(this).text().replace(/([^\x00-\x80]|\w)/g, "<span class='letter'>$&</span>"));
});

anime.timeline({loop: true})
    .add({
        targets: '.ml11 .line',
        scaleY: [0,1],
        opacity: [0.5,1],
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 700
    })
    .add({
        targets: '.ml11 .line',
        translateX: [0,$(".ml11 .letters").width()],
        easing: "easeOutExpo",
        duration: 700,
        delay: 100
    }).add({
    targets: '.ml11 .letter',
    opacity: [0,1],
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    duration: 600,
    offset: '-=775',
    delay: function(el, i) {
        return 34 * (i+1)
    }
}).add({
    targets: '.ml11',
    opacity: 0,
    duration: 1000,
    easing: "easeOutExpo",
    delay: 1000
});
```

Comment: Have you added jquery to your solution?
You can get it here: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp

Comment: Seems you haven't jQuery loaded

Comment: @Patte probably not as the question isn't even tagged with jQuery ;)

Comment: Yes, working. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

jQuery is the solution: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_get_started.asp.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```